# Converting dateTime to UTC

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc

When converting the current date and time, got from `DateTime.Now`, `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now)` converts it correctly.

However, if a `DateTime` object is created, it does not convert it, it leaves it the same:

```
// get the local time as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2020, 2, 5, 11, 59, 53, 0, DateTimeKind.Local); // tried with and without DateTimeKind specified
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString());

// convert it to UTC
DateTime UTCdateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime);
Console.WriteLine(UTCdateTime.ToString());
```

This prints:

```
2/5/2020 11:59:53 AM
2/5/2020 11:59:53 AM
```

The second timestamp should be UTC.

Why is this?

Note: the values plugged in above I was using to test. I need to get them from `dateTimePicker` controls.

Comment: Are you in the UK?

Comment: No, Australia. Currently in AEDT.

Comment: Are you trying to get the current Utc time? Have you tried `DateTime.UtcNow` instead?

Comment: I need to get the values from two `dateTimePicker`s. The values above, I was just plugging in to test with .NET fiddle.

Comment: It works absolutely fine on [Rextester](https://rextester.com/DYMUY34580) (UTC+1), and on my local machine (UTC+9).

Comment: @John, could you try it on .NET Fiddle, maybe it's an issue with that.

Comment: @WashingtonA.Ramos I tried that, same issue.

Comment: [.NET Fiddle's local time is UTC](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kByEA4)

Comment: @John oh I see. I was not aware of that. I should try it within my application itself.

Comment: I was about to say what John said. I suggest trying it on C# Interactive on Visual Studio when you want to test little snipplets.

Comment: The real question should be "what is time zone of machine you are trying this code" and not "Are you in XXXX"...

Comment: Did you consider using DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime? This will always contain the Timezone and can be converted to UTC

Comment: @Sebastian I ended solving it with `DateTime`. I tested it and convinced myself it works. However, now that you mention it, I'm tempted to check again, that's just my OCD. If it doesn't work, I'll use `DateTimeOffset` ;)

Comment: Why dont you use DateTime.UtcNow ?